# Prompt user for a password and hide the input with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'd like to have a prompt that queries a password inside a Sublime Text 2/3 plugin and hide the input with `****`. This does not work and even crash SublimeText:

```py
import sublime_plugin, sublime

class ExampleOneCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.show_input_panel("Enter Password", "", self.on_done, self.getpwd, None)

    def getpwd(self, password):
        stars = "*" * len(password)
        self.window.show_input_panel("Enter Password", stars, self.on_input, self.getpwd, None)

    def on_done(self, password):
        pass

    def on_input(self, password):
        pass
```

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written above, when I invoke your command it crashes the plugin host with a `RuntimeError` of `maximum recursion depth reached`. The reason why this is happening is perhaps best illustrated with this simple example:

```py
class ExampleTwoCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.show_input_panel("Sample", "Initial Text", None, self.on_change, None)

    def on_change(self, pwd):
        print('on_change("%s")' % pwd)
```

If you invoke the command and then immediately look in the Console without interacting with the input, you see this:

```
>>> window.run_command("example_two")
on_change("Initial Text")
```

So essentially your problem is that when the input panel opens, it tells the `on_change()` handler about the initial text, and your command responds to that by immediately opening the input panel again, which does the same thing and then kaboom.

To get around that you need to have a guard in place that stops this from happening; for example:

```py
class ExampleThreeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.initial = ""
        self.window.show_input_panel("Sample", "", None, self.on_change, None)

    def on_change(self, pwd):
        if self.initial != pwd:
            stars = "*" * len(pwd)
            self.initial = pwd
            self.window.show_input_panel("Sample", stars, None, self.on_change, None)
```

Now the `on_change()` handler will only re-open the input handler if the text changes.

A consequence of this is that the text that ultimately gets returned to you is the initial text with your edits, so when `on_done` is finally called, the text that it gets is going to contain all `*` characters due to the manipulations here.

To get around that you would need to check the `password` given in `on_change` to see what characters it contains that are not `*` characters to know what was actually typed, and then keep that separate so that you keep the text as the user is editing it. Similarly if the length of the password changes you need to throw characters that you've saved away because someone has removed a character or characters from the input. You would also need to take care of the case of the user moving the cursor inside the panel as well (such as inserting characters).

With all of that said, the simplest example of something that does all of this is the following, which uses the `password` setting to tell the input panel that no matter what is typed, it should be obscured:

```py
class ExampleFourCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        panel = self.window.show_input_panel("Enter Password", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        panel.settings().set("password", True)

    def on_done(self, password):
        sublime.message_dialog("Password entered: '%s'" % password)
```

I'm not sure if this setting is supported in Sublime Text 2 though; it's used in Sublime Merge's password input when you're entering passwords there, so possibly it was added around then.

If Sublime Text 2 support is required, the next best thing would be something like this combination of plugin and an associated key binding (which I think should work there, but I don't have a copy to test with):

```py
_password = ""
class ExampleFiveCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        panel = self.window.show_input_panel("Enter Password", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        panel.settings().set("password_input", True)

        global _password
        _password = ""

    def on_done(self, password):
        sublime.message_dialog("Password entered: '%s'" % _password)


class PasswordInputCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, character):
        global _password
        _password += character
        self.view.run_command("insert", {"characters": '*'})
```

```
    { "keys": ["<character>"], "command": "password_input", "context": [
        { "key": "setting.password_input", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    ],
    },
```

Here the key binding executes a custom command when you enter a character, but only when the view has the setting `password_input` and its set to true. The associated commands keep track of the actual password in a string and opening the input panel applies the setting. The result is that as long as the panel is open and you're typing in it, the custom command grabs the text and keeps it.

For a more complete example you would also need to bind the backspace key in case the user wants to do corrections. You can also use the selection in the view in order to determine where in the existing password the character pressed should go.

On the whole, the `password` setting is the cleanest solution, though.

Comment: For the last alternative, you can't simply add the inserted character to the `_password` variable, because it may have been inserted at a different position and technically input panels support multiple selections, too, although hardly practical in password prompts. Most notably, however, there could have been a selection *before* the character was inserted, which is even more annoying to keep track of.

Comment: Yeah; the [PR example](https://github.com/ericmartel/Sublime-Text-2-Perforce-Plugin/pull/35) that I looked at in the Perforce package naively assumes that the only changes being made are adding characters to the end or removing them, so it breaks rather horribly if you move the selection around somehow. On the whole I think the `password` setting is the best solution though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution @OdatNurd. `ExampleFourCommand` works perfectly on ST3. Not on ST2 though. `ExampleFiveCommand` nearly works on ST2, but if you type `abc<backspace><backspace><backspace>def`, it will output `abcdef`, whereas it should output `def` only.

Comment: Yes for that case you need an extra binding on backspace using the same context and a command that can adjust the password. Although as @FichteFoll mentioned in the comment above, the whole thing generally needs to be smarter because it's also possible to change the cursor location in the input. in which case the assumption that the changes go on the end of the view is also wrong.

Comment: I generally suggest abandoning ST2 entirely. Trying to maintain support for it in this day and age is only hindering you.